# Display older post first

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to display the older post first in wordpress:

I'm using this code to get the list of post of the current category:

```
<ul id="submenu_productos" class="clearfix">
    <?php
        $IDOutsideLoop = $post->ID;
        while( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            foreach( ( get_the_category() ) as $category )
                $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=' . $category->category_nicename . '&orderby=date&order=desc&showposts=100');
            if( $my_query ) {
                while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li<?php print ( is_single() && $IDOutsideLoop == $post->ID ) ? ' class="test"' : ''; ?>>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> |
            </li>
    <?php
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

if I change `"&order=desc&"` to `"&order=ASC&"` it  still has the order in the same way. what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't you order on date and not title?

Comment: I change that too. still shows the same

Comment: try this `orderby=modified`, just to see whether it's the wrong variable you're using or not

Comment: Last I can suggest is try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you by any chance using the Post Types Order plugin? There is a setting for this that overrides the ordering (the auto-sort ordering option).

Comment: oh yeah that was it! haha thanks. the problem now is that it arrange me the list with the older post first when I open the page it opens with the newest post. How can I override it?